# Is it necessary include Google Play Servicies in apk?

Tags: android, google-play-services, libraries

I am afraid with that. Is it necessary to include Google Play Services with our apk? If it were an external library the response is YES. But in this case, Android forces us to download latest Google Play Services version, so the code must be in the device...

The problem that I see is that every app with this library will use the same code that can have the device, thus saving space.

Practical case: I had an application with admob which is 800KB. Now, using Google Play Services is 2.8MB.

Could someone explain me that?
Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Because most users have the latest version installed on their devices, you do not need to include the entire Play Services lib in your build. If they don't have it installed, or if they do not have the latest version then your code might not work correctly.

If the user has Google Play then they will get a dialog letting them know that their Google Play Services is out of date and needs updating. If they don't have Google Play then you can choose what to do, for example you can alert the user that the app will have a limited functionality. If your app can't run without Google Play Services and the user doesn't want to install/update Google Play Services then your app will not work properly. Using an outdated libs in your project might work however you would be using them at your own risk as they won't be updated.

Comment: So, in case that the play servicies is not updated the user may see a FC and that is not good...

Comment: I just want play services to show ads. If I include the lib, GooglePlayServicesUtil.isGooglePlayServicesAvailable(this) returns SUCCESS and the ad is shown. If I don't include the lib, GooglePlayServicesUtil return a NoClassDefFoundError.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly you don't need to include it in your apk - you can pretty much assume it's on the phone and up to date. The increase in size means that you are including it in your apk. To exclude it from the apk delete it from your `libs` folder.

If you get errors then you need to add it as a library to your app. You can do that by going into your project's properties then clicking on Android on the left and then in the bottom section add Google Play Services from your workspace as a library (that is on Eclipse).

Comment: Add it only if fails in my devices? I think that is not a good idea. May it works on my devices but not in other people, generating a FC...